# Is every Compound Poisson distribution a Mixture model?

Tags: probability, distributions, mixture-distribution, compound-distributions, infinite-mixture-model

We have two models:

1. Let $N \sim \hbox Poisson (\lambda)$ and let $(X_k ; k =1,2,3,...)$ be a a sequence of independent and identically distributed random objects (random variables, vectors or stochastic process)  and independent of $N$. Consider the following Compound Poisson object
   \begin{equation}\label{abc}\tag{I}
   Y = \sum_{j=0}^N  X_{j} = \sum_{j=0}^\infty \mathbf \chi_{[N>j]} X_j 
   \end{equation}
   ($\chi$ is the haracteristic function of a measurable set)
2. The second class of models is the [Mixture Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_model). The most basic version of this model is
   $$Y \sim \sum_{g=1}^G \eta_g f(. | \theta_g)$$
   where $G$ is the number of components (sometimes unknown), $f$ is the component density and is fixed and known; the component-specific parameters are $θ_g$ (often vector-valued) and $\eta_g$ are the weights, non-negative and summing to $1$. There are some generalizations from these models, for example, where different components are allowed different parametric forms:
   $$Y \sim \sum_{g=1}^G \eta_g f_g(. | \theta_g)$$

I am interested in making inferences on the models given by (\ref{abc}) in the case that $X_1, X_2,...$ are time series and I would like to know if I can use techniques that are used in mixtures models. So, I would like to know to experts if it is possible to express (\ref{abc}) as a mixture model?

Comment: Sure it is possible: but $G=\infty$ and that likely precludes many mixture model estimation techniques. Moreover, treating the Compound Poisson purely as a mixture neglects the strong relationships among the mixture weights imposed by the Poisson distribution of $N.$

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I thought it was important not to invest in wring blood from a stone. I would just like to better understand why treating the composite Poisson purely as a mixture neglects the strong relationships between the weights of the mixture imposed by the Poisson distribution of $N$?